# WSO2 BAM integrate Data Service

Tags: wso2, dashboard, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-bam

I m new to BAM. I have to create a gadget/graph to display on dashboard some values from database. I could do this through [Gadget Generation Tool](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM201/Gadget+Generation+Tool).

But now my requirement is that I want to get these values from a Data Service. How should I integrate data service with my BAM.

What approach should I take and how to start with this work?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is an architectural problem. The gadgets generator basically creates a JSON data service written in Jaggery (server-side Javascript framework), then basically connects to this data service and visualizes it in a graph/table. So, you are already using the data service concept. You can do the same (and much more) using data services server. It allows you to expose your data sources as a service with security, reliability, etc. I'd encourage you to download WSO2 Data Services Server. It's available [here](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/).

Comment: hi... Thanks for the reply...

then how would I use this data service in BAM... this is what I m stuck at...

Comment: hmmm, you are already using it... because your gadget is rendering the graph after consuming the data from the data service... you can check the gadget.xml which you can locate from the 'about' section in the gadget. I would also advice you to look get a general idea about Web Services, SOA and front-end/back-end separation.